# Number of retries in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

While setting AWS Lambda settings we have a retry count of 2 (max) by default.

[image]

**But when I am adding DynamoDB Trigger to it, there is retry option of 10,000**

[image]

So which settings is true. If exception occurs will the retry will be 10,000 times or 2 times. Can someone please guide me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing are two different things.

The first one (retries of 2) is for [asynchronous](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html) invocation of lambda. This means that you (or some service) invokes lambda function and it does not wait for the results. In this case lambda service will try to invoke your function in the background 2 times, on condition that the original attempt fails.

The second one (retries of 10000) is for [Event Source Mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventsourcemapping.html). This is a special process in the lambda service which monitors data sources (in this case DynamoDB stream) and invokes your function on your behalf. You are not involved in this process, except for setting up the mapping. In this case the event source mapping invokes your lambda [synchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html). It will try doing this 10000 times in case of errors. This is a **separate** setting from the retry setting used for asynchronous invocations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In you first paragraph you have suggested -> ` In this case lambda service will try to invoke your function in the background 2 times.` ... But "In what case". You mean every asynchronous invocation will happen 1 time and plus 2 retries in total?

Comment: Why the asynachronous being retried? You have not mentioned in your anwer.

Comment: Yes, 1 normal attempt to run your function, and 2 retries if it fails. That's how lambda works by default. You can set retry to 0 if you don't want any retries in case the first invocation fails.

Comment: Well, you never mentioned "if it fails" in your original answer, so I was confused.

Comment: @Unbreakable I see. I just added it to the answer.

Comment: I could not undestand your answer at all, so I am going to ask in real world scenario. Suppose I am sending an event in from DynamoDB, and I have intentionally set a wrong handler as Lambda function name so to mimic an INVOCATION Error. Now if the retry in DynamoDB is set to 5, and retry in Lambda is set to 2 (which is the default), How many times I will see my lambda to be invoked/retried. Note that my lambda is asynchronous.

Comment: "This is a separate setting from the retry setting used for asynchronous invocations." - This is what I need to understand. I am confused between Lambda Retries and Retry from Dynamo DB. Please give me  a simple example so I can comprehend it.

Comment: Unfortunately, your scenario is not possible. In event source mapping lambda is invoked **synchronously only**.  You can't change that.  Retry of 2 does not apply here. The only retry that applies is 5.

Comment: Yes I know its confusing. AWS if rather famous for having similar naming conventions for different things leading to a lot of headache.  The example is what you already provided. If you use DynamoDB with lambda you use event source mapping. It is only synchronous invocation. For asynchronous invocation, for example, you can manually use aws cli with [--invocation-type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) of `Event`.

Comment: I thought just adding async in my handler makes my lambda asynchronous

Comment: @Unbreakable LIke in node.js? `async` in node.js has nothing to do with how lambda is executed. This is only how you write functions in node.js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210915/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-marcin).

Answer (score 2):

> So which settings are true. If an exception occurs will the retry will
>   be 10,000 times or 2 times.

Both retries have different purpose and meaning.

1. Lambda retries mean your lambda function has been triggered and some error occurred while during the processing event so it will retry once more to process the same event.

[image]

2. In this your lambda functioned is not triggered yet as the error occurred during pulling a stream from the event source.

[image]

> **Lambda reads items from the event source and triggers the function.**

this retires isn't in the context of a function. once it pulls the event from the stream then it will trigger the lambda with desired stream event.

You can look into the [below diagram](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example.html) for board picture  that is the same example with kinesis stream 
[image]

You can read more this below

[invocation-async](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)

[create-event-source-mapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html)

[understand-your-lambda-event-retries](https://blog.rowanudell.com/understand-your-lambda-event-retries/)

[lambda-with-ddb-stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)